# How to find the distance from vertical for a given 3x3 rotation matrix

Tags: geometry, rotations

Given a $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix for a camera in a fixed position, how can I find the angle between where the camera is pointing and the vertical z axis?

To clarify, if the camera is imagined at the center of a globe, I am looking for the line of latitude that it would be pointing at, without caring so much about longitude (though that would be a nice bonus).

I've tried looking at conversions to Euler angles, but it seems like that is providing too much information, as rotations around each of the axis interact with each other to influence the final line of latitude - I would need a way to combine all three rotations into a final number.

Comment: What is the original direction of the camera before rotation? And are you applying the rotation to the camera, or to the rest of the world to bring it into camera-relative coordinates?

Comment: @beepboop could you please clarify better the set up of the problem and what exactly you are asking for? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. The rotation is applied to the camera. I guess it was confusing to bring cameras into it, as the question applies to any body being rotated. The original orientation has the camera facing the north pole, using the analogy above.

Comment: @beepboop Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- find the (fixed) axis of rotation by $R\vec v=\vec v$
- use $\cos \theta=\frac{\vec v\cdot \vec w}{|\vec v||\vec w|}$ to determine the angle between $\vec v$ and any vector $\vec w$

Comment: -1: The question didn't ask for the angle between the *rotation axis* and the $z$-axis.

Comment: @Rahul sorry I didn’t get what exactly what about the OP is asking for, I’ll request some clarification about it and revise, thanks

Comment: I was able to use this approach, I applied the rotation matrix to [0, 0, 1], then determined the angle between the result and [0, 0, 1] again.

Comment: @beepboop well done! I’m happy for that. Bye